# Using Parseval's identity to evaluate a definite integral.

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

Using the Parseval’s identity prove that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^{4}(x)dx= \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

As far as I know to do this problem we need to find the fourier coefficients of $\cos^{2}(x)$.  I am getting $a_{0} = 1$. Also $a_{n}$  is $0$   and     $b_{n}$ is $0$. On using the Parseval’s identity I am not getting $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ as the answer

Any correction or help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother evaluating the Fourier series. We know that $\cos^2(x)=\frac12+\frac{\cos(2x)}2=\frac12+\frac{e^{i2x}+e^{-i2x}}4$. So, by [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20Parseval%27s%20identity,uncountable%20infinity%20of%20basis%20vectors), $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^4(x)\,dx=2\pi\left(\frac14+\frac1{16}+\frac1{16}\right)$.